# Is it possible to display all of the functions that SymPy tries during `simplify()`?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

The SymPy [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#simplify) state the following:

> SymPy has dozens of functions to perform various kinds of simplification. There is also one general function called simplify() that attempts to apply all of these functions in an intelligent way to arrive at the simplest form of an expression.

I am using SymPy as a tool to help me relearn maths, so it would be really useful if I could view all of the functions that SymPy tries.

Is is possible to display all of the functions that SymPy tries during `simplify()`?  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of `simplify` is [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/simplify/simplify.py#L385). According to it, SymPy attempts the following operations, most of which are documented in [simplify module docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html) (the page you linked is from SymPy tutorial, which does not go into details.)

```
cancel(expr)
_mexpand(expr).cancel()
together(expr, deep=True)
factor_terms(expr, sign=False)
hyperexpand(expr)
piecewise_fold(expr)
besselsimp(expr)
trigsimp(expr, deep=True)
expand_log(expr, deep=True)
logcombine(expr)
combsimp(expr)
sum_simplify(expr)
product_simplify(expr)
quantity_simplify(expr)
powsimp(expr, combine='exp', deep=True)
powsimp(expr)
expand_power_exp(expand_mul(expr)))
exptrigsimp(expr)
```

To try these directly, import

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.simplify.simplify import sum_simplify, product_simplify
from sympy.core.function import _mexpand
```

However, `simplify` does not just try these methods one by one: most of them are used only when the expression matches some pattern, and some of them are used in combinations.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping that I could do something like increase the log level to see the logic in action, but it was a long shot.